# Regex to check consecutive number with spaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to find some Regular Expression that will identify a string:

**Question 1**

With more than 4 consecutive numbers followed by white space:

e.g.

```
123456
something 1 2 3 4 5 and 1 2 3 4 5
12 34   5
1234
```

**Question 2**

With more than 4 consecutive number words with white space:

e.g.

```
one two three four
one    two three    four  five
onetwothreefour
```

**Question 3**

Is there any smart way to do this for other languages too?

Thanks

Comment: I am no regex expert, that's why I am asking for help. I have tried the following for Q1, but it is not working: `[0-9\s+]`

Comment: 1. This cannot be done using regex as it involves maths. 2. Number words cannot be even solved using maths so you need a library to convert number words to numbers and then do the maths.

Comment: @Richard, I think this is fairly easy to do using a proper function instead of doing it entirely using Regex. Which language were you using?

Comment: Thanks @Piyush. I am looking to do it in a number of languages. I can build up an array of stored number words. I am doing this in javascript, so you are probably correct, a function may be better than regex for Q2 and Q3.

Comment: is it limited to digits only? "numbers" seems a bit misleading. For example, "ten" ?

Comment: Yes, just digits. `zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine`. (I am trying to filter out contact details from a string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want numbers between 0 and 9, these should do:

Q1: `(?:[0-9]\s*){4,}`

Q2: `(?:(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\s*){4,}`

Comment: Thank you, those two lines work perfectly.  Just one question, how do I make them repeat? i.e. if the sequence repeats. e.g. `1 2 3 4 and 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Another question, how do I combine the above into just one regex?

Comment: @Richard By combining, do you want to accept a mix of the two? (`one 2 3 four` for example)

Comment: Yes please. I am trying to stop someone from entering in a phone number for example

Comment: @Richard In this case, you can use `(?:(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|[0-9])\s*){4,}`.

Comment: @Richard For your earlier question, I am not sure of the answer as I have never used `NSRegularExpression`, but there is probably a way to iterate over every match in one string.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help, you know your stuff!  However, I cannot seem to get the `?:` to work. Is the entire regex:   `(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|[0-9‌​)\s*){4,}`

Comment: @Richard I forgot a closing bracket in my comment, but I edited it now.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of anything smart now, but for example:

[`1 *2 *3 *4 *(5 *(6 *)?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/oY4OyO/1)

[`1 *2 *3 *4 *(5 *(6 *)?)?|one *two *three *four *(five *(six *)?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/oY4OyO/2)